# ITelephony interface method answerRingingCall() not working

Tags: android, phone-call, telephony, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I want to `receive Incoming call` from my application, I am using `ITelephony.aidl` to `End and receive call`. I have written the following code to answer the call on button press, mostly I am able to end the call on all the devices but when I try to receive a call it's not working.

This (call answer) code is working fine on some devices that I have tested  on (Motorola** e3 6.0 android security patch 1 Jun 2016 , honor 4.4.4, YU 4.4.4. etc)`it's not working on`(Xiaomi note 4 6.0.1, lyf 6.O.1 android security patch 1 march 2017)` may be the issue is causing because of android security patch update on latest versions.

I think google has allowed some `permission` only for `system apps` for `security` reason, in latest Update of **`android security patch 1 Jun 2016 to 1 March 2017.`**

Please help, Thank you

```
    private void m13352k() {
     try {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) 
        getSystemService("phone");

        Method declaredMethod = 
        Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName()).
        getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony", new Class[0]);
        declaredMethod.setAccessible(true);
        ITelephony iTelephony = (ITelephony) 
        declaredMethod.invoke(telephonyManager, new Object[0]);
        iTelephony.silenceRinger();
        iTelephony.answerRingingCall();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            m13350j();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            m13349i();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
    private void m13349i() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(callerIdConfig.mediaButton());
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT", new KeyEvent(0, 79));
        sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, callerIdConfig.callPrivileged());
        intent = new Intent(callerIdConfig.mediaButton());

        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT", new KeyEvent(1, 79));
        sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, callerIdConfig.intentCallPrivileged());
        intent = new Intent(callerIdConfig.headsetPlug());
        intent.addFlags(1073741824);

        intent.putExtra("state", callerIdConfig.m13633f());
        intent.putExtra("name", callerIdConfig.headset());
        sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

---

```
    private void m13350j() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG");
    intent.addFlags(1073741824);
    intent.putExtra("state", callerIdConfig.m13633f());//0
    intent.putExtra("name", callerIdConfig.headset());
    sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

    intent = new Intent(callerIdConfig.mediaButton());
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT", new KeyEvent(0, 79));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, callerIdConfig.intentCallPrivileged());
    intent = new Intent(callerIdConfig.mediaButton());

    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT", new KeyEvent(1, 79));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, callerIdConfig.intentCallPrivileged());
    intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG");
    intent.addFlags(1073741824);

    intent.putExtra("state", callerIdConfig.m13629e());//1
    intent.putExtra("name", callerIdConfig.headset());//"Headset"
    sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
}
```

---

I get below log when I click to receive call from my application please provide solution

> 06-27 12:33:34.153 1543-2055/? W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Nei
>   ther user 10206 nor current process has
>   android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE. 06-27 12:33:34.153 1543-2055/?
>   W/System.err: at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1443) 06-27
>   12:33:34.154 1543-2055/? W/System.err: at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1475)
>   06-27 12:33:34.154 1543-2055/? W/System.err: at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:675)
>   06-27 12:33:34.154 1543-2055/? W/System.err: at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:675)
>   06-27 12:33:34.154 1543-2055/? W/System.err: at
>   com.android.phone.PhoneInterfaceManager.enforceModifyPermission(PhoneInterfaceManager.java:1896)
>   06-27 12:33:34.154 1543-2055/? W/System.err: at
>   com.android.phone.PhoneInterfaceManager.answerRingingCallForSubscriber(PhoneInterfaceManager.java:1199)
>   06-27 12:33:34.154 1543-2055/? W/System.err: at
>   com.android.phone.PhoneInterfaceManager.answerRingingCall(PhoneInterfaceManager.java:1191)
>   06-27 12:33:34.154 1543-2055/? W/System.err: at
>   com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub.onTransact(ITelephony.java:93)
>   06-27 12:33:34.154 1543-2055/? W/System.err: at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:458) 06-27 12:33:34.155
>   959-2000/? W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: not allowed to send
>   broadcast android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG from pid=24565, uid=10206
>   06-27 12:33:34.155 959-2000/? W/System.err:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send
>   broadcast android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG from pid=24565, uid=10206
>   06-27 12:33:34.155 959-2000/? W/System.err: at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18158)
>   06-27 12:33:34.155 959-2000/? W/System.err: at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:18662)
>   06-27 12:33:34.155 959-2000/? W/System.err: at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:475)
>   06-27 12:33:34.155 959-2000/? W/System.err: at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2719)
>   06-27 12:33:34.155 959-2000/? W/System.err: at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:458) 06-27 12:33:34.156
>   959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10 (has extras) } to
>   com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.media.ui.MediaNotificationManager$PlaybackMediaButtonReceiver
>   requires Intent.android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.157
>   959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10 (has extras) } to
>   com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.media.ui.MediaNotificationManager$PresentationMediaButtonReceiver
>   requires Intent.android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.157
>   959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10 (has extras) } to
>   com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.media.ui.MediaNotificationManager$CastMediaButtonReceiver
>   requires Intent.android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.157
>   959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10 (has extras) } to
>   com.google.android.apps.books/android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver
>   requires Intent.android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.157
>   959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10 (has extras) } to
>   com.google.android.youtube/com.google.android.libraries.youtube.player.PlayerUiModule$LegacyMediaButtonIntentReceiver
>   requires Intent.android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.157
>   959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10 (has extras) } to
>   com.google.android.music/.playback.MediaButtonIntentReceiver requires
>   Intent.android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.157
>   959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10 (has extras) } from
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (pid=24565, uid=10206) is not
>   exported from uid 10103 due to receiver
>   jio.cloud.drive/com.newbay.syncdrive.android.ui.musicplayer.MusicIntentReceiver
>   06-27 12:33:34.157 959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial:
>   receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10
>   (has extras) } to
>   com.UCMobile.intl/com.ucmusic.notindex.RemoteControlEventReceiver
>   requires Intent.android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.157
>   959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10 (has extras) } to
>   com.jio.media.jiobeats/com.jio.media.mobile.apps.jiobeats.notifications.RemoteViewsReceiver
>   requires Intent.android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.159
>   959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10 (has extras) } to
>   com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.media.ui.MediaNotificationManager$PlaybackMediaButtonReceiver
>   requires android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.159
>   959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10 (has extras) } to
>   com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.media.ui.MediaNotificationManager$PresentationMediaButtonReceiver
>   requires android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.159
>   959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10 (has extras) } to
>   com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.media.ui.MediaNotificationManager$CastMediaButtonReceiver
>   requires android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.159
>   959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10 (has extras) } to
>   com.google.android.apps.books/android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver
>   requires android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.160
>   959-7332/? W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: not allowed to send
>   broadcast android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG from pid=24565, uid=10206
>   06-27 12:33:34.160 959-7332/? W/System.err:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send
>   broadcast android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG from pid=24565, uid=10206
>   06-27 12:33:34.160 959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial:
>   receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10
>   (has extras) } to
>   com.google.android.youtube/com.google.android.libraries.youtube.player.PlayerUiModule$LegacyMediaButtonIntentReceiver
>   requires android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.160
>   959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10 (has extras) } to
>   com.google.android.music/.playback.MediaButtonIntentReceiver requires
>   android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.160
>   959-7332/? W/System.err: at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18158)
>   06-27 12:33:34.160 959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial:
>   broadcasting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10
>   (has extras) } from smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   (pid=24565, uid=10206) is not exported from uid 10103 due to receiver
>   jio.cloud.drive/com.newbay.syncdrive.android.ui.musicplayer.MusicIntentReceiver
>   06-27 12:33:34.160 959-7332/? W/System.err: at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:18662)
>   06-27 12:33:34.160 959-7332/? W/System.err: at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:475)
>   06-27 12:33:34.160 959-7332/? W/System.err: at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2719)
>   06-27 12:33:34.160 959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial:
>   receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10
>   (has extras) } to
>   com.UCMobile.intl/com.ucmusic.notindex.RemoteControlEventReceiver
>   requires android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.160
>   959-7332/? W/System.err: at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:458) 06-27 12:33:34.160
>   959-979/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON flg=0x10 (has extras) } to
>   com.jio.media.jiobeats/com.jio.media.mobile.apps.jiobeats.notifications.RemoteViewsReceiver
>   requires android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED due to sender
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer (uid 10206) 06-27 12:33:34.160
>   24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer W/System.err:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send
>   broadcast android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG from pid=24565, uid=10206
>   06-27 12:33:34.160 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
>   06-27 12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
>   06-27 12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>
> W/System.err: at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:3218)
>   06-27 12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.sendOrderedBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:855)
>   06-27 12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.sendOrderedBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:426)
>   06-27 12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer.callrecorder.activity.FullscreenCallerActivity.m13349i(FullscreenCallerActivity.java:253)
>   06-27 12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer.callrecorder.activity.FullscreenCallerActivity.m13352k(FullscreenCallerActivity.java:314)
>   06-27 12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer.callrecorder.activity.FullscreenCallerActivity.access$200(FullscreenCallerActivity.java:35)
>   06-27 12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at
>   smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer.callrecorder.activity.FullscreenCallerActivity$2.run(FullscreenCallerActivity.java:212)
>   06-27 12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>   06-27 12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>   06-27 12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 06-27
>   12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5767) 06-27
>   12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 06-27
>   12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>   06-27 12:33:34.161 24565-24565/smartcall.talktime.balance.phone.dialer
>   W/System.err: at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

========================================================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this solution works perfectly on some devices which shows call notification in status bar ,this solution supports after **android security patch 1 march 2017** update  *(this solution may not work on some devices of Samsung and oppo or other)* still looking for perfect solution if any one finds please update , thank you

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Arrays;

 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
public static PendingIntent pendingIntent;

//start service on call notification get
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Log.e("onNotificationSag", "titleaction"+ Arrays.toString(sbn.getNotification().actions));

            if (sbn.getNotification().actions != null) {
                for (Notification.Action action : sbn.getNotification().actions) {
                    Log.e("onNotificationSag", "action" + action.title);
                    if (action.title.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Answer")) {
                        pendingIntent = action.actionIntent;
                        //  try {
                        //receive call automatically
                        pendingIntent.send();

                        //} catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
                        //     e.printStackTrace();
                        //}

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

} 
}
```

---

### add following permissions and code to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />



<service
        android:name=".NotificationService "
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

---